# What is the right way to set up system ROS2 on Windows with Conda Python?

Tags: ros2, windows, windows10, anaconda

ROS2 Humble, Windows 10 64bit.

I'm a ROS beginner, but am fairly familiar with Python. While installing ROS2 for Windows, I followed all the steps for a standard system installation but did not install a system Python, because I keep everything contained in environments.

I didn't [just download this](https://medium.com/robostack/cross-platform-conda-packages-for-ros-fa1974fd1de3), as it seems to only support ROS1. I am also not using WSL as I would like to use the viz tools, and I don't know how much I trust [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg) yet. And ROS2 is native on Windows!

I made a new ros2 environment in Conda with python 3.8, which is where I installed the pip dependencies. Upon finishing all the requirements and trying to run `ros2` I got the classic `failed to create process.` error.

I set the environment variable `COLCON_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` to `C:\Users\me\Miniconda3\envs\ros2\python.exe` which seemed to be what the `local_setup` scripts looked for, but that didn't seem to change anything. I'm now inclined to believe that this is only for colcon, not the rest of ROS2.

I then made a symlink from `C:\Python38` to `C:\Users\me\Miniconda3\envs\ros2\` (where the environment lives) so that the shebangs on all the demo python scripts would work. Things seem okay now! The cpp-py hello world is working.

My question is: Is this okay? Will something break further down the line? Is there a better way to do this? My largest fear is something about other ROS2 processes starting that don't activate the conda environment, but I don't know a ton about ROS.

Comment: Robostack supports ROS 2 Humble and it's how I use ROS 2 on Windows in a Conda environment. I don't have a good answer off the top of my head on how to make sure the native Windows installer and Python in a Conda environment interoperate correctly.

Comment: @danzimmerman guess I didn't look into the up-to-date robostack docs! That follows the containerized philosophy better than a system ROS2 install. I'll probably continue to use my current setup (if it aint broke...), but the moment I get suspicious behavior I'll just switch to their build.